# C1001 internal compiler error due to vector initialization like arrays

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

```cpp
struct record
{
    double mid_exam;
    double fin_exam;
    double assignment[5];
    double score;
    char grade;
};

struct student
{
    string name;
    record math;
    record science;
};

int main()
{
    vector<student> students {
        // { name, math, science}
        { "John", {10.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Elton", {20.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Houston", {30.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Ashton", {40.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Lee", {50.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Jack", {60.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Christiano", {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Lukas", {80.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Sahid", {90.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Ryan", {90.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} }
    };
}
```

I'm making students grade management program with vector for student.

I initialized vector-like arrays. I didn't write the score and grade number, which will be calculated in grade computation function.

Visual Studio printed error message, internal error happend inside compiler.

At first, I made this code with

```cpp
student students[10]
```

array and it worked fine.

I changed only `array` to a `vector` and I can't find out what is wrong now.

Comment: "_internal error happend inside compiler_" - No matter how you write code, that's not acceptable. Which version of VS are you using? Did you include any external tools in your toolchain? If you are running vanilla, send a bug report - or upgrade.

Comment: I'm using korean language so message shows in korean. It's "컴파일러에서 내부 에러가 발생했습니다."  I don't know exactly message in english. I erarsed vector initialization code and made a student struct and students.push_back(temp);  this code works fine. Only at initialization code, error happens.

Comment: "An internal error has occurred in the compiler." is google translate's take on it and sounds very familiar. That happens when the compiler vendor has bugs. But, you have bugs in your code too. You've properly initialized your first level of subobjects with `{` and `}` but `assignment` is not taken care of and after that you have two fields.

Comment: As you said, I put in 0 number in every not assigned field, and it works fine. When I use ```student students[10] array``` I don't need to assign every field, but ```vector``` doesn't allow it. I wonder how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you haven't enclosed `assignment` with braces in your initializer list, but that shouldn't crash your compiler.

- Click on the `Feedback` icon (top right) in Visual Studio.
- Click on `Report a problem`.
- In the search field, put

  > `Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage with improperly initialized std::vector`
- Click on the link matching the search. It should be the first match and it's reported by me.

What pops up is this:

*This improperly initialized std::vector makes the compiler crash.*

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct record
{
    double mid_exam;
    double fin_exam;
    double assignment[5];
    double score;
    char grade;
};

struct student
{
    std::string name;
    record math;
    record science;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<student> students{
        { "John", {10.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}},
        { "Elton", {20.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}}
    };
}
```

*The workaround is easy. I just initialize it properly.*

```
std::vector<student> students{
    { "John", {10.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, 0, 0}, {70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, 0, 0}},
    { "Elton", {20.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, 0, 0}, {70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, 0, 0}}
};
```

You can also vote on the issue.

An alternative, if you don't want to have to enter `score` and `grade` in your initializer list, is to add a constructor for `record` and to use `std::array` instead of regular arrays:

```
#include <array>

struct record
{
    record(double m, double f, const std::array<double, 5>& a) :
        mid_exam(m), fin_exam(f), assignment(a), score{}, grade{}
    {}
    record() : record({}, {}, {}) {} // default constructor, delegating to the above
    double mid_exam;
    double fin_exam;
    std::array<double, 5> assignment;
    double score;
    char grade;
};
```

Which makes it ok to initialize it like this:

```
std::vector<student> students{
    {"John", {10.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}}, {70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}}},
    {"Elton", {20.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}}, {70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}}        }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a9P7tg)

Comment: @Hangman83032 You're welcome! Here's another, more verbose, [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3hqJs8) where I've split it up a bit more and added streaming etc.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. I agree with your answer and approach to explaining to other answers owner.

Comment: @Mannoj You solved the problem so I don't think you should remove the answer just because I happen to not agree with the approach in the solution. Someone else might find it useful.

Comment: I feel if two answers are correct then the better approach should be preferable.

Comment: @Mannoj Not always. I tend to read more than the accepted answer or the one with the highest number of votes - and sometimes I find one I like better among the other answers. It's nice to have options :-)

Comment: Introduced again with improvement. Thanks

Comment: @Hangman83032 If you go into Visual Studio and follow the instructions for how to get to my trouble report and vote on that report, it _may_ make MS more eager to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc (7.4.0), no compilation internal error but the code is not accepted. It works by simply identifying the different levels of initialization, as already mentioned in comments:

```
int main()
{
    vector<student> students {
        // { name, math, science}
        { "John", {10.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60} }, {70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60} } },
        { "Elton", {20.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60} }, {70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60} } }
    };
}
```

Edit: this code is still not being compiled with VS (see comment). However, with gcc + options `-Wall -pedantic`, it does not raise any warning. Same with gcc 8.3.0

Edit 2: with `clang -Wall -pedantic`, it also compiles, without any warning. Clang 7.0.1-8

Edit 3: a warning appears with `Wextra` option, as indicated by Ted Lyngmo

Comment: It doesn't help in Visual Studio: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/D-3d9k)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Strange. I don't have VS to test. Does it work with: `{ "John", {10.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, },` ? With gcc, I originally put this additional comma, and then removed it when I saw it was useless with gcc

Comment: You can test it by changing the code in the [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/D-3d9k). It's set up to use the VS compiler - and dies because of an internal compiler error just like it does for OP.

Comment: @TedLyngmo OK, it does not work with VS. Besides, no warning with `gcc -Wall -pedantic`. So, either gcc is too permissive even with `pedantic` option, or VS should accept it. I would be happy to understand what happens here. Anyway, the fact that VS is crashing is not normal

Comment: VS _should_ accept it (but warn if `/W4` is used i.m.o.). It's a bug.  Try `-Wextra` with `g++` and you'll get the warnings. If you turn on treating warnings as errors, you get [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xqiqHX).

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right, warning with Wextra. Exactly same behavior for g++ and Clang

Answer (score 0):

Modify the lines like below :

```
{ "John", record{10.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, 0, ' '}, record{70.5, 90, {80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, 0 , ' '} }
```

The problem is due to unidentified values during object creation.
Try the above code this will solve your problem. Record object is not
getting properly build.

The actual error was reproduced as below:

> fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
>   1>(compiler file
>   'd:\agent_work\2\s\src\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 187)
>   1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the
>   program near the locations listed above.

Comment: This works until you compile your code with a compiler with better diagnostics and turn on treating warnings as errors (which is a pretty common setting). [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hdZbjp). VS doesn't even complain with `/W4`.

Comment: But its always good to solve the warnings in program to improve application stability. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I think your solution is just as stable in runtime as mine as long as noone reads from those uninitialized members. I don't see the benefit of omitting to brace enclose the sub-objects though. It makes it harder to read/maintain the code i.m.o.

Answer (score -1):

Following worked for me in VS2015:

````
struct record
{
    double mid_exam;
    double fin_exam;
    double assignment[5];
    double score;
    char grade;
};

struct student
{
    string name;
    record math;
    record science;
};

int main()
{
     student students[10] =  {
        // { name, math, science}
        { "John", {10.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Elton", {20.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Houston", {30.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Ashton", {40.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Lee", {50.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Jack", {60.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Christiano", {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Lukas", {80.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Sahid", {90.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} },
        { "Ryan", {90.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60}, {70.5, 90, 80, 85, 20, 70, 60} }
    };
}```
````

Comment: no, I want to declare ```vector<student> students```. array works fine to me also.